# Relation between the real line and circle

Tags: algebraic-topology

In M Nakahara's *Geomertry, Topology and Physics*, he states (example 2.4) that the  the quotient space(set of equivalence classes) of the real line under the equivalence relation:

$x$ is related to $y$ if $x-y=2n\pi$, $n$ is an integer.

is the circle $S^1$. I can see why that is so. For instance, in the quotient space, $0,2\pi,4\pi$ are all in the same element(in same equivalence class); this is also true for the circle. However, this is also true for the ellipse, or for any closed curve with the perimeter $2\pi$. Why does the quotient space have to be just a circle then?

Comment: The ellipse is homeomorphic to the circle.

Answer (score 3):

In topology, there is no distinction between a circle and an ellipse. They are both $S^1$. The distinction only appears when you have a metric and start measuring distances and curvature.

Comment: What about a square loop? Does the same hold for it?

Comment: @ManiJha Yup. Any polygon with non-intersecting sides. And many others.

Comment: Yes. If two spaces can be continuously deformed into each other, then they are homeomorphic (topologically indistinguishable). Imagine a circle made of *rubber*, then you can easily stretch it into the shape of a square and vice-versa.

Comment: @Berci Except you normally have to be careful when you say ‘continuously deform’ because a cylinder deformation retracts to a circle but they’re not homeomorphic.

Comment: @Berci Homeomorphisms aren't really about continuous deformation. That's a homotopy. They are related, but different enough that you have to be careful. For instance, two circles meeting in a point, and two triangles sharing an edge may be continuously deformed to one another, but they aren't homeomorphic.

Comment: Yes, yes, right, it's not rigorous at all, I just wanted to visualize it for the OP.